# Transforming text into it's appropriate RTL representation

Tags: right-to-left, bidi

I'm looking for any java library which would help in transforming a piece of text into it's appropriate RTL representation.

For e.g. the hebrew/arabic text when read from a file would be in the LTR representation, however after the transformation it ought to be shown in it's RTL format.

The requirement comes up since in the case of html's we can specify the dir as rtl or ltr. However when we want to have a text variant or a sms variant of the text, the stylesheets don't come into play at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues that come into play with RTL content. The first is the right alignment of the display. There's nothing you can do about that unless you have control of the output routines that are being called.

The second issue, which is arguably more important, is the base directionality of the text. This you can control to a certain extent by adding [bidirectional formatting characters](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Embedding) to your content.

For example, given a string in *s*, you could set the base direction to RTL, with something like this:

```
String[] lines = s.split("\n");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  sb.append("\u202B");   // right-to-left embedding 
  sb.append(lines[i]);
  sb.append("\u202C\n"); // pop directional formatting
}                  
s = sb.toString();
```

What this is doing is splitting the text into multiple lines, then adding a *right-to-left embedding* character at the start of each line, and a *pop directional formatting* character at the end of each line.

The reason it is done line by line is because the embedding override only lasts for the length of the paragraph.

[Example code on Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/TWYxT2)

[Markup example for comparison](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLhxB)